# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ya existe la columna «user_id» en la relación «django_admin_log»

Tags: python, django, postgresql, backend

I am currently developing a project in Django 2.0.2, but when migrating my models I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ya existe la columna «user_id» en la relación «django_admin_log»
```

This is all that the console shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle
fake_initial=fake_initial,
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 122, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
field,
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 421, in add_field
self.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 117, in execute
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "C:\Users\aleja\Documents\GitHub\proyectoHelping\Proyecto\proyectoHelping\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ya existe la columna «user_id» en la relación «django_admin_log»
```

This is the model that is giving me problems:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Perfil(models.Model):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    nombre = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name='Nombre',
        help_text='Ingrese su nombre'
    )
    apellidos = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
        verbose_name='Apellido',
        help_text='Ingrese su Apellido'
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='avatars/',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Avatar'
    )
    cumpleaños = models.DateField(
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Fecha de nacimiento',
        help_text='Seleccione su fecha de nacimiento'
    )
    universidad = models.ForeignKey(
        'principal.Universidad',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Universidad',
        help_text='Seleccione la universidad a la que pertenece'
    )
    facultad = models.ForeignKey(
        'principal.Facultad',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Facultad',
        help_text='Seleccione su Facultad'
    )
    carrera = models.ForeignKey(
        'principal.Carrera',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Carrera',
        help_text='Seleccione su carrera'
    )
    publicaciones = models.ForeignKey(
        'evaluaciones.Publicacion',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Publicaciones',
        help_text=''
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.usuario.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Perfil'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Perfiles'
```

My intention is to use the User model that brings Django by default and add other fields, but migrations are not executed for that error

Comment: this error is not about the your model Perfil. you get this error because django_admin_log table has already relation with user table in database but somehow in your model class this relation is newly added. So when you try to make migration you get this error. Can you post your latest migation file which is in the migration directory in your project

Comment: thanks, at the end of several hours of code revision, I managed to repair the error, the problem was (as you said) that there was already a relationship with the user table, the solution I gave was to create a new database and then do the migrations, then move the data from one base to another, luckily I did not have data in the user table, perhaps others could not work this solution, but for practical purposes, it was enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of several hours of code revision, I managed to repair the error, the problem was (as you said) that there was already a relationship with the user table, the solution I gave was to create a new database and then do the migrations, then move the data from one base to another, luckily I did not have data in the user table, perhaps others could not work this solution, but for practical purposes, it was enough